# djnago rest framework 404 page not found

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a ModelViewSet like this :

```
class MeetingListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   
      queryset = Meeting.objects.all()
      serializer_class = MeetingtSerializer
```

and this is urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
```

]

and this is router :

```
    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register('meeting', MeetingListViewSet,'meetinglists')

    urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(router.urls)),
  
    ]
```

when i try the path http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/meeting/meetinglists to to get  data i get 404 page not found error  . which url pattern should i enter in url to access to MeetingListViewSet?
and this is the error i got :

```
    Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/meeting/meetinglists
Using the URLconf defined in mizban_events.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
api/ login/ [name='login']
api/ logout/ [name='logout']
The current path, api/meeting/meetinglists, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in `urls.py`. It should not be `rest_framework.url`, instead, it should be `<your_app_name>.url`

Point it to the `url.py` of the django app instead.